# htaccess rewrite is using only 2 files php

Tags: .htaccess

How htaccess syntax?

I have 3 files (php)
a. premium.php

b. direktori2.php

c. direktori_det2.php

this Flow:

1. example.com/AbelPutra-com (inside premium.php) and i direct to direktori2.php file

   --->  RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-()/&]+)/?$ direktori2.php?NamaToko=$1 [NC,L]

   **this is OK**
2. example.com/AbelPutra-com/Modern-Karaoke (inside direktori2.php) and I direct to direktori_det2.php file

   --->  RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-()/&]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-()/&]+)/?$ direktori_det2.php?NamaToko=$1&NamaProduk=$1 [NC,L]

   **this is Problem **

   or this error Syntax?

When I running in number 2, server read with rewrite in number 1 (always read number 1)

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Without detailed looking into this rule I found this mistake:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-()/&]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-()/&]+)/?$ direktori_det2.php?NamaToko=$1&NamaProduk=$2
```

You use `NamaProduk=$1` instead of `NamaProduk=$2`.

Comment: The easiest way is just to swap them, so RewriteRule #2 should come first in .htaccess file.

Comment: @Roman, wow....its working...thank you very much.... Its surprise for me...hahaha...

Comment: @Abel, you're welcome. You can also rewrite your rules to make sure they match only one URL type, but rearranging them works OK (as in this case).

Comment: @Roman. Ok.ok...thanks for your kind attention and advice..(sorry my english bad hehe..)

Comment: Roman, can you give me solution for my other problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986271/httaccess-primary-domain-ok-but-addon-domain-be-problem